# Set of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, polynomials

I want clarification on the following question:

Let $\{c_0,c_1,c_2,\dots,c_n\}$ denote a set of $n+1$ distinct elements in $\mathbb{R}$. Define the set of $n+1$ polynomials.

$$f_j(x)=\prod_{k=0,k\ne j}^n \frac{x-c_k}{c_j - c_k} $$

Note that $f_j(x) \in P_n(\mathbb{R})$ with the property
$$f_j(c_l) = \left\{ \begin{align} 0&& if&& j\ne l\\ 1&& if&& j= l \end{align} \right.$$

Does this imply that $f_0(x) = \{c_0,0,...,c_n=0\}$

Meaning, does $x$ have to take on values only in set $\{c_0,c_1,c_2,\dots,c_n\}$ or does it equal $\{0,0,\dots,c_0,0,0,\dots,0\}$ taking in values from all $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the statement says is what happens when $x$ is one of the $c$'s, which can be proven from the definition of $f$. The definition of $f$ itself implicitly specifies the value of the function on every $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Have I used the function correctly? Does $f_0(x)$ equal one of the two above?

Comment: @DisplayName: I don't even understand what you wrote. $f_0$ is a function that expects a real number as input and produces a real number as output, not a set of any kind.

Comment: Okay I think I understand now, so $f_0(c_0) = 1$,$f_1(c_1) = 1$ etc.

Comment: @DisplayName: Perfect. I don't know the context of this question but the reason to consider this function is actually because of its property, which means that we can multiply it by a constant and add such functions together to create a function that has specified values at $n+1$ points.